# How to expand UICollectionView contentSize when paging enable?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm making a simple `UICollectionView` with a paging mechanism enabled, and everything works fine. Though, when scroll to the last page the number of the cells are not fully visible in the screen, and the last page contains some cells of the previous page.

How do I expand the `contentSize` of the `UICollectionView` so that the last page doesn't contain any cells of the previous page?

An example [here](https://github.com/lequysang/github_zip/blob/master/DragCollectionViewCell.zip): the `UICollectionView` scrolls horizontally with 6 cells, this way:

- **Page 1:**

  `cell0 - cell1 - cell2 - cell3`
- **Page 2:**

  `cell4 - cell5` is expected, but unexpectedly

  `cell2 - cell3 - cell4 - cell5`

How to change it?

**SUMMARY:**

I want to set

`collectionView.contentSize = numberOfPage * collectionView.frame`

**NOT**

`collectionView.contentSize = numberOfCell * (cellFrame + spacing)`

Comment: It should not happened actually. Can you plz post code snippet if any.

Comment: I try:[collectonView setContentSize] in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear but It not work because contentSize will be rewrite in datasource.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` and override the `collectionViewContentSize` method. I subclassed `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` so I wouldn't have to re-write all the layout code.

I'm building a 4x4 grid, so my method looks like this:

```
- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
{    
    NSInteger itemCount = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];
    NSInteger pages = ceil(itemCount / 16.0);

    return CGSizeMake(320 * pages, self.collectionView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Side note, when you use a custom layout, you lose the ability to set the some of the display properties in the Interface Builder. You can set them programatically in the `init` method of your custom UICollectionViewLayout subclass. Here's mine for reference:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setup
{
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(65.0f, 65.0f);
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 15;
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(7.5f, 7.5f, 30.0f, 7.5f);
    [self setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
}
```

Comment: I have been told that this sort of thing could cause a huge memory footprint because the whole collection view would be "shown" and the reusability of cells would not be possible.  Is this true?

Comment: UICollectionView is already a subclass of UIScrollView and having contentSize is natural for it, I don't think you have to worry about cell reuseablity because all the cells are never visible at all.

Comment: `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize()` is what you need. If it's not valid, just `collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()` before you get contentSize.

Comment: How to set collectionViewContentSize in Swift 3.0

Answer (score 2):

For horizontal paging

```
if(CollectionView.pagingEnabled)
{

    int numberOfPages = floor(collectionView.contentSize.width /
                      collectionView.frame.size.width) + 1;
                             CGFloat 
    float requierdWidth=self.collectionView.frame.size.width*numberOfPages;

    self.Layout.footerReferenceSize=CGSizeMake(requierdWidth-self.collectionView.contentSize.width,0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer works well, though for our code we had one section per page. So it meant the override for our layout class was just

```
-(CGSize) collectionViewContentSize {
    return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.frame) * 
                 [self.collectionView numberOfSections],
                 CGRectGetHeight(self.collectionView.frame)) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the content with the `viewDidLayoutSubviews:` method. This method gets called when the collection view and all the cells are placed in the `view`, so that you can adjust cell.

Comment: It not work, cellForItemAtIndexPath also call when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` and create your custom layout to manage these kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer that doesn't require any subclassing.

In -viewDidLoad, calculate how many items per page you will have and how many pages you will have. Store these values in properties.

```
    self.numberOfItemsPerPage = NumberOfRows * NumberOfColumns;
    self.numberOfPages = ceilf((CGFloat)self.items.count / (CGFloat)self.numberOfItemsPerPage);
```

Then in -collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection: just lie to it:

```
    return self.numberOfItemsPerPage * self.numberOfPages;
```

You will of course have more cells than content, right? So in -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: just return nil for the extra cells:

```
    if (indexPath.item > [self.items count] - 1) {
    //We have no more items, so return nil. This is to trick it to display actual full pages.
    return nil;
    }
```

There you go: full, scrollable final page. In my opinion, the horizontal scroll mode should just default to this.

Comment: Pretty sure a cell can't be nil :( I tried this and got this error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the collection view's data source did not return a valid cell from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: for index path <NSIndexPath: 0xc0000000001a0016>`