# UICollectionView content size not correct?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want my `UICollectionView` to `scroll` when the `contentSize.height` becomes bigger than the `contentOffset.y + frame.size.height`, so I set up an observer, like so:

```
[self.collectionView addObserver:self 
                      forKeyPath:@"contentSize" 
                         options:0 
                         context:NULL];
```

I then have an `NSLog` to check it's `contentSize`.

The problem is that it doesn't update its `contentSize` until you add an additional panel after the one that just changed it. That means that it's `contentSize` is actually more than it says it is whenever the newest object stretches further down than any others.

Is this a common `UICollectionView` bug? Is there another way of seeing when it expands?

EDIT:

More info. This also happens when using

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
```

and also happens if i call the `NSLog` after a few seconds of the new panel being displayed (so it's on screen and set up by that point). It still displays the wrong value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852004/how-to-expand-uicollectionview-contentsize-when-paging-enable

Comment: please reference to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21717985/411522)