# Custom Footer view for UICollectionview in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I am re-writting an objective-C app of min in swift and decided that a collection view works better then a tableview in my case. So i have the collectionview all set up exactly how i want it and now i need to add a footer to my collection view.

In objective-C it was very easy for me, all i did was create a UIView, add objects to it, and add it to my tableview like this.

```
self.videoTable.tableFooterView = footerView;
```

Now i've been trying in my collection view to get a similar solution, however i've had no luck so far.

Is there a simple `.collectionviewFooterView` or something that i can add my UIView to?

**EDIT**
i found similar ideas [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852004/how-to-expand-uicollectionview-contentsize-when-paging-enable) if that helps create an answer

***EDIT***

I've been thinking on ways to achieve this so right now my idea is to add the footer view to the end of the collection view using the following code:

```
var collectionHeight = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize().height

footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, collectionHeight, screenSize.width, 76)
```

The only issue i'm having with this workaround is i need to add more space to the contentView of the colletionView and i am having no luck with that

***My Solution***

I solved it using a work-around (not the prettiest but it works), i add the UIView to the uicollectionview using a simple

```
footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, collectionHeight - 50, screenSize.width, 50)
self.collectionView.addSubview(footerView)
```

and set the layout insets using this:

```
alLayout.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 52, 2)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample code? Also can you provide where you set the above code please?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Collection views handle headers and footers differently than table views. You'll need to:

1. Register your footer view class using:

   ```
   registerClass(myFooterViewClass, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "myFooterView")
   ```
2. Either set the `headerReferenceSize` on your collection view layout or implement `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:` in your `delegate`.
3. Return the footer view from the following method in your `dataSource`:

   ```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
       let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "myFooterView", forIndexPath: indexPath)
       // configure footer view
       return view
   }
   ```

I think that's everything!

Comment: i use a custom class for my layout and i don't think it has footer in it

Comment: Right - this will only work if your layout derives from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

Comment: Gave you the check because it's a good answer and would normally work in most cases

Comment: I had to use .self on the end of myFooterViewClass, like so: collectionView.register(MyFooterViewClass.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "myFooterView")