# Adding a UIView to the bottom of a UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewController` embedded inside a `UINavigationController` which in turn embedded inside a `UITabBarController`.

[image]

I want to add a `UIView` to the `UICollectionViewController` just above the tab bar (shown by red rectangle).

[image]

I have the `UIView` created separately as a nib file.

```
import UIKit

class BottomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    fileprivate func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BottomView", owner: self, options: nil)
        view.frame = self.frame
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

And I initialize and add it in the `UICollectionViewController` like so.

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    fileprivate var bottomView: BottomView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let yPos = view.bounds.height - (tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.size.height + 44)
        bottomView = BottomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: yPos, width: view.bounds.width, height: 44))
        collectionView?.addSubview(bottomView)
    }

    // ...

}
```

I figured if I substract the combined height of the bottom view plus the tab bar from the entire view's height, I should be able to get the correct `y` position value. But it's not happening. The view is getting added but way off screen.

How do I calculate the correct y position without hardcoding it?

[Example demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2cxxt0pz5hahbv/CollectionBottomView.zip?dl=0)

Comment: What about creating the BottomView off the UICollectionView?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean..

Comment: You could add the bottom view as the footerView of CollectionView

Comment: Your BottomView should scroll along with collectionView?

Comment: @AravindAR Would it scroll with the collection view?

Comment: @RodrigoMorbach No, it should stick to the bottom

Comment: What's the reason on of adding your view inside the collection view? what if you let it be a separated view behind the collection view?

Comment: @AhmadF You mean above the collection view? I tried that too. Added it to the view instead of the collection view but got the same result.

Comment: I was thinking about something like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gkqa0ysp7xa1j0n/collectionview-uiview.png?dl=0

The green is your BottomView and the blue is your collectionview. They are siblings.

Comment: @Isuru try adding the    let yPos = view.bounds.height - (tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.size.height + 44)
        bottomView = BottomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: yPos, width: view.bounds.width, height: 44))
        collectionView?.addSubview(bottomView) 
in the layoutIfNeeded

Comment: How about the re-usable view ?

Comment: What are you showing in your screenshot, the red rectangle should represents your custom view, which mean that it is *behind* the collection view; You don't even need to add it to the collection view, just add it to the main view, setup the appropriate constraints and you should be good to go...

Comment: Use simple UIViewController with UICollectionView and UIView...

Comment: call ur bottom view frame in viewdidappear  and         view?.addSubview(bottomView)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest adding the `BottomView` to the `UICollectionViewController`'s `view` rather than to the collection view itself. This is part of the problem you're having.

You're also trying to set the frame of the `BottomView` in the `viewDidLoad()` method using values from `view.bounds`. The CGRect will return `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` at this point because the layout has yet to take place, which is most likely why your positioning is off. Try moving your layout logic to the `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` method and see if that helps.

A better approach would be by setting auto layout constrains rather than defining a frame manually, this will take a lot of the leg work out for you.

Here's a quick example:

```
self.bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.insertSubview(self.bottomView, at: 0)
self.bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
self.bottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
self.bottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
self.bottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
```

You can apply autolayout logic in your `viewDidLoad()` and it should work correctly.

You can find some more information on setting autolayout constraints programatically here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds what you want to achieve is exactly the footer view for the UICollectionView.

A footerView is like a view that will stick to the bottom of the collectionView and wont move with the cells.

This will help you add a footer View: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26893334/3165112

Hope that helps!